# Does anyone know how to add a folder and its contents given its directory to a zip file using Zip Utils?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, directory, zip

I am using Zip Utils and creating a zip file. I am trying to add a folder and its contents given its directory to the zip file, but neither the ZipAddFolder() nor the ZipAdd() functions are adding anything to the zip file. I can create a new folder within the zip file using ZipAddFolder() but it doesn't let me add the folder I want with its contents. It doesn't even add any existing files for me. My code is shown below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "zip.h"

TCHAR zipFilename[] = TEXT("C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\test3.zip");

TCHAR directoryPath[] = TEXT("C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\");
TCHAR entryName[] = TEXT("NewFolder");

HZIP hz = CreateZip(zipFilename, 0);
if (hz == 0) {
// error...
}

//BOOL c = CopyFile(TEXT("C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\test3.zip"), TEXT("C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\test.zip\\"), 0);             // I even tried copying a file in using CopyFile but this didn't work either
            
//ZRESULT res = ZipAddFolder(hz, TEXT("C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\"));   // This does not add anything to the zip file
ZRESULT res = ZipAddFolder(hz, entryName);        // This creates a new folder in the zip file named "NewFolder"

//ZRESULT res = ZipAdd(hz, entryName, TEXT("C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\test1.zip"));  //This does not add anything to the folder

if (res != ZR_OK) {
 // error...
}

CloseZip(hz);
```

Has anyone been able to successfully add a folder and its contents to a zip file using Zip Utils, or any file from a different location into the zip file, for that matter? Are there any other better ways to do this - create a zip file and add a folder and its contents to it, or just zip up a folder? I have already tried XZip and libzip - XZip did not work for me and for libzip, I couldn't get all the installations to work properly. Are there any other easy header libraries I can just add to do this?

Comment: What is Zip Utils?

Comment: @RetiredNinja https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-Clean-Elegant-Simple-Cplusplus-Win

Comment: Ah, not going to sign up to download it. Good luck!

Comment: @RetiredNinja You don't have to sign up to download it, it's free. Just click on "Download source files".

Comment: Which redirects you to a page requiring you to sign in. *shrug*

Comment: When you click "Download source files" you are greeted with the following message: "You must logon to download zip files." So, indeed, good luck.

Comment: The library seems to work fine to add files one by one, but it has no special utility to add a folder with its files, so you'll have to do it yourself scanning the folder using winapi. As for the ZipAddFolder utility, you have to use / instead of \, so for example `ZipAddFolder(hz, "root/path1/path2");`. The nice thing with open source is ... well, it's open so you can have a look at it